# Is there a way to merge ImageCollections in Earth Engine without the "system:index" property being modified?

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2

I was trying to merge two Sentinel-2 image collections (one based on date filtering and one based on image IDs), then pull in the matching [Sentinel-2: Cloud Probability dataset](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/COPERNICUS_S2_CLOUD_PROBABILITY) to apply cloud masking to the merged collection.

However, it appears that performing a merge operation modifies the image "system:index" values (which are needed for the join with the Cloud probability dataset). The merge adds "1_" and "2_" prefixes to the "system:index" of the images in the merged collection. This stops any subsequent joining with another dataset from working.

The following is a simplified code of what I am trying to achieve. The problem is that the join with the Sentinel-2: Cloud Probability returns an empty set of images due to the prefixes added by the merge operation. If I simply join to one of the un-merged image collections, such as `col1`, the join works fine.

The "system:id" of the images are not modified by the merge operation and so I tried joining on the "system:id" instead of "system:index" but I received an error indicating:

> FeatureCollection (Error)
> Cannot filter on 'system:id'. Apply the filter to property 'system:index' instead.

Is there a way to merge image collections without the "system:index" properties being modified?

````
var testArea =  ee.Geometry.BBox(146.5, -18.3, 146.55, -18.2);
          
// Create two image collections. One based on image IDs, the
// second based on date filtering.
var IMAGE_IDS =  ["COPERNICUS/S2/20170104T002702_20170104T002921_T55KDV"];

var manualImages = IMAGE_IDS.map(function(id) {
    return ee.Image(id);
  });
  
var col1 = ee.ImageCollection(manualImages);
    
var col2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
    .filterBounds(testArea)
    .filterDate('2018-01-01', '2018-01-05');

// Verify the system:index prior to merge
var col1IDs = col1.aggregate_array('system:index');
print(col1IDs);
// ["20170104T002702_20170104T002921_T55KDV"]
  
var col2IDs = col2.aggregate_array('system:index');
print(col2IDs);
// ["20180104T002659_20180104T003132_T55KDV"]

// Merge the two collections into one collection
var mergedCollection = col1.merge(col2);

var mergedIDs = mergedCollection.aggregate_array('system:index');
print(mergedIDs);
// List (2 elements)
// 0: 1_20170104T002702_20170104T002921_T55KDV
// 1: 2_20180104T002659_20180104T003132_T55KDV
// The system:index has been modified to include 1_ and 2_ as prefixes

// Attempt to bind the S2_CLOUD_PROBABILITY dataset to these images
// Extract from https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/COPERNICUS_S2_CLOUD_PROBABILITY
var s2Clouds = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_CLOUD_PROBABILITY')
  .filterBounds(testArea);

// Join S2 with cloud probability dataset to add cloud mask.
var s2SrWithCloudMask = ee.Join.saveFirst('cloud_mask').apply({
  primary: mergedCollection,
  secondary: s2Clouds,
  condition:
      ee.Filter.equals({leftField: 'system:index', rightField: 'system:index'})
});

print(s2SrWithCloudMask)
// ImageCollection (0 elements)
// No match due to 1_ and 2_ prefixes from merge.```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to merge image collections without the "system:index" properties being modified?

No, it is not possible. This is because of two fundamental properties of Earth Engine collections:

1. `system:index` values are unique within a collection (no two features have the same ID).
2. Collections are processed in a “streaming” fashion: processing each feature does not require knowledge of previous features.

If a merge operation did not modify the IDs then to avoid violating property (1), it would need to remember previous IDs and violate property (2).

---

What you *can* do is join on a property you create that isn't `system:index`, which will thus not be modified by the merge.

```js
function preserveId(image) {
  return image.set('original_id', image.get('system:index'));
}

...

var col1 = ee.ImageCollection(manualImages).map(preserveId);
    
var col2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
    .filterBounds(testArea)
    .filterDate('2018-01-01', '2018-01-05')
    .map(preserveId);

var mergedCollection = col1.merge(col2);

var s2Clouds = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_CLOUD_PROBABILITY')
  .filterBounds(testArea)
  .map(preserveId);

var s2SrWithCloudMask = ee.Join.saveFirst('cloud_mask').apply({
  primary: mergedCollection,
  secondary: s2Clouds,
  condition:
      ee.Filter.equals({leftField: 'original_id', rightField: 'original_id'})
});

print(s2SrWithCloudMask);
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/d6cfe50ba052d878cf71c00ad0ffa5db